# dual boot linux and win10 on laptop with SSD caching

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, uefi

I have HP Elitebook 840 G2 with 1TB HDD and 32GB SSD (separate M2 card) as cache I see it as RAID during boot process. Disk is MBR partitioned. I want to install Linux (Ubuntu) alongside Win10.

Problem: there is no option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, only "erase disk and install Ubuntu" and "something alse". And if I press "something else" to use manual partitioning I don't see existing partitions. However I can see them from terminal (a lot of /dev/sda-s).

Update: I figured out that disk is a dynamic disk, that's because of SSD caching.

Comment: You cannot install Ubuntu in UEFI mode since Windows exists on drive using MBR partitions.

Comment: Right, but I don't need exactly UEFI mode, BIOS with GRUB is OK too.

Comment: Problem is that in BIOS mode there is either no option to install Ubuntu and keep Windows on another partition. Ubuntu installer offers me to choose HDD for bootloader and there is no partitions visible, only sda. I think if I choose it, all HDD will be formated and thats not what I want.

Comment: :Let us start from the beginning.  Is Windows installed on a HDD with GPT or MBR partitions?  Your question is confusing, so I will just ask that question myself, because you didn't specify.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I think it should be MBR, because if I set up laptop to use UEFI instead of BIOS, it won't find any OS to boot.

Comment: You need to confirm, "you thinking its MBR", is not helpful.  I need a defenant answer one way or another.

Comment: Widows is installed on HDD with MBR partitions. I'll edit my post to make it clear.

Comment: Hmm dynamic disk? How exactly was this "caching" set up? Doesn't sound like Intel SRT or Windows ReadyBoost. Actually, I doubt that caching is the cause of dynamic disk.

Comment: It was factory settings. There is Intel Rapid software preinstalled on PC and drives are cofigured as RAID 0. It looks like SRT, how can I check it?  Wikipedia states: Basic partitions are restricted to a fixed size on one physical disk, that's why I assumed that chaching is the cause of dynemic disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I reinstalled Windows with use of Basic instead of Dynamic disk and without SSD caching and it works out.
Now there an option to install Linux alongside Windows and I can mount HDD partitions without any problems.